# Restrict filestream container data being deleted in filesystem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, filestream

Just observed on SQL Server Express 2008 R2, I am able to delete the filestream files for each table row manually in filesystem. Upon delete the application throws an error

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

Is there a way to restrict delete operation on the filesystem while using filestream to avoid this?

I am following this article [Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx)

Under "File System Streaming Access" it states that

> Because file operations are transactional, you cannot delete or rename FILESTREAM files through the file system.

However, I am able to delete them.

Comment: not really - only by restricting the permissions for those folders...

Comment: Can you give me a little hint how to do this? I have the same domain user for SQL Server authentication & machine login.

Comment: From the linke you provided "Only the account under which the SQL Server service account runs is granted NTFS permissions to the FILESTREAM container. We recommend that no other account be granted permissions on the data container." - which is exactly what you see...

Comment: this in turn means that your setup is not secure - the machine login and the SQL Server service account must be different and the machine login should NOT have access to those parts of the filesystem!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Yahia, if you can post that as a reply I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you provided

> Only the account under which the SQL Server service account runs is
>   granted NTFS permissions to the FILESTREAM container. We recommend
>   that no other account be granted permissions on the data container.

which is exactly what you see...

This in turn means that your setup is not secure - the machine login and the SQL Server service account must be different and the machine login should NOT have access to those parts of the filesystem!